# Event cannot find basic function on spark.apache.org

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm newbee for Spark, So need searching the basic function meanning of the rdd functions like "join", "reduceByKey".
[Official website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#package)  comes the first choice.

When input function name on the left top of the page.
[the small input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otzCt.png)

I cannot even find the functions above make me confucius. Now I can only search the usage on google one by one.

Could Anyone tell me how to search the functions, should i know which package the functions come ? 
Or cannot fuzzy search the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the docs for the joins under the [PairRDDFunctions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) class. I agree that the search feature is not very good, but I have a few suggestions.

- Read the [RDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) class docs. It contains many of the fundamental operations and the text at the top is informative.
- I find the [programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html) to be about as useful as the reference docs. They might be especially helpful for you because the programming guide comes with much more explanation.

Comment: yeah! I'll follow your advise. But still suggest to improve the search.